# I'm being logged out after checking out any file in Visual Studio TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

We have these Web API projects, and I'm responsible for redesigning the UI, So I have to make changes in a lot of files, and after every check out, I'm being logged out of the website, and it's so annoying, is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: How did you specify credential to connect to TFS/VSTS?

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the PAT in your code to connect to TFS. In this way, you don't need to login every time. Check the code below:

```
 String collectionUri = "https://xxxx.visualstudio.com";
 VssBasicCredential creds = new VssBasicCredential("", "6ztnrtjdd3xxxxxxxxxxxeo277tgiuiq");
 VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(collectionUri), creds);
```